# Raspberry LCD IP display format

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ip, lcd

I'm working on a little project with a Raspberry Pi, and I need to display the IP adress of the PI on an LCD screen.

I followed this tutorial :
https://learn.adafruit.com/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi/python-code

It seems to work fine, however there is a problem displaying the IP. Instead of displaying "192.168.0.68", it shows "fe80::779b:a7a1:9282:f4d5". It shows the time just fine ("Sep 19 18:20:41").

Being new to programming, I couldn't find the problem, so here I am asking for help

Thanks in advance !

Comment: that's your IPv6 address, so... no problem?

Comment: Specifically, I am looking for a way to convert the display format, in one that can be used to SSH to the Pi ?

Comment: that is a valid IPv6 address. unless your ssh is so old it doesn't understand ipv6, that is an address you could for ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `netifaces` package to be useful for obtaining the IP address. The link below explains well about its basic usage

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces

Below is an example to obtain the ip address in the python interpreter.

```
>>>import netifaces
>>>addr = netifaces.ifaddresses('en1')
>>>addr
{18: [{'addr': 'e4:ce:8f:30:98:0c'}], 2: [{'broadcast': '192.168.1.255', 'addr': '192.168.1.22', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0'}], 30: [{'addr': 'fe80::e6ce:8fff:fe30:980c%en1', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::'}]}
>>>addr[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr']
'192.168.1.22'
```

Note: I use `'en1'` because I'm on a Mac. In the Pi typically this would be `'eth0'`